# Bind Principal to MyCustomUser class as method argument in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know you can get a username easily in a Spring controller by including `Principal` as a method argument like:

```
@GetMapping("/username")
@ResponseBody
public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
    return principal.getName();
}
```

But I am ultimately going to want access to members of a `MyCustomUser` class that I instantiate from a repository with a `findBy` method. I can put a helper method in the Controller to do the lookup and return the user based on `principal.getName()`, but **can I go a step further and bind to `MyCustomUser` directly, like**

```
@GetMapping("/stuff")
@ResponseBody
public String stuff(MyCustomUser user) {
    return user.thing();
}
```

I was looking into creating a converter like ([Ref](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder)):

```
@Component
public class PrincipalToMyCustomUserConverter implements Converter<Principal, MyCustomUser> {

    private MyCustomUserRepository userRepository;

    public PrincipalToApplicationUserConverter(MyCustomUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public MyCustomUser convert(Principal source) {
        return this.userRepository.findByUsername(source.getName());
    }

}
```

But I don't know if that's an appropriate way to grab the repository, and I don't know how to pass the repository when registering the converter ([Ref](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that the converter you're proposing is not appropriate.  Your converter can convert from an object of type `Principal` to an object of type `MyCustomUser`, however, there is no `*Principal*` by which to convert.  The magic behind the principal injection is that Spring actually gets this from the `SecurityContextHolder`, it is not deserialized from request...though fields present in the request allow Spring to create the `Principal`.  If you truly want to inject `MyCustomUser`, use a `ModelAttribute`.  `ModelAttributes` are available to all of your Spring controller methods.

I generally like to keep stuff like this in it's own class, so I would define a class that held this and other @ControllerAdvice in one place, something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeControllerAdvice {
  @Autowired
  private MyCustomUserRepository myCustomUserRepository;

  @ModelAttribute
  public MyCustomUser getUser(Principal principal) {
     return myCustomUserRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
  }
}
```

The above should suffice to make MyCustomUser available to all methods.  I would note that you probably want a little error handling here, like skip over if principal is null and whatnot, also have your `findByUsername` method return an Optional so your can address empty returns.

see: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Comment: I'll have to check the documentation to understand how this works, but I like it. And I learned the meaning of "Spring." Thanks!

Comment: What did you have in mind regarding "skip over if principal is null," how could I achieve that? I am trying to use something like `@PostMapping("/signup") public void signup(@RequestBody MyCustomUser user)`, but at that point the `Principal` is null.

Comment: In the model attribute method I would simply put a check at the first line, if principal == null return null.  On all endpoints unsecured endpoints you're not going to be able to auto inject the user, but that's obvious.